# какой заголовок html кода использовать в коде парсера по яндекс переводчику на питоне

Tags: html, python, бот

я пишу парсер - переводчик по сайту [яндекс переводчик](https://translate.yandex.ru) Я сделал запрос и сделал команду для занесения слова в переводчик, мне нужно достать сам перевод, но я не знаю по какому заголовку html кода нужно обращаться, попробовал многие варианты

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

sesssion = requests.Session()

new = requests.get('https://translate.yandex.ru/')
html = bs(new.content, 'html.parser')

slov = {
    'text': 'как твои дела?'
}

answ = sesssion.post('https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=ru-en', data=slov)
answ_bs =  bs(answ.content, 'html.parser')

print(answ_bs.select('.textinput textlayer textlayer_measurer textlayer_measurer_layer textlayer_measurer_translation')[0].text.strip())
```

Comment: Нужно открыть инспектор браузера (F12) и на вкладке Сети смотреть какие запросы отправляются и повторить это. Например, перевод можно получить по GET запроса на адрес https://dictionary.yandex.net/dicservice.json/queryCorpus но в него еще кучу параметров указывать

Comment: @gil9red  я так и делал, только понять не могу, какие же все таки запросы нужно юзать

Comment: почему бы не воспользоваться [`API`](https://translate.yandex.ru/developers)?